# 'Decades of research {has/have} shown.'

Tags: prepositions, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, subjects

> Decades of research *has/have* shown.

Should this sentence use a singular or plural verb?

- *decades* is plural
- *research* is murky

I'd be inclined to write 'has'. Should it be 'have' instead? Why or why not?

Answer (score 9):

You only have one subject in your sentence: "decades of research".

Research modifies decades, but decades is definitely plural, so the correct sentence is

> Decades of research have shown

The same is true the other way:

> A line of cars **is** standing on the road.
>   A bag of apples **costs** $2.

Comment: While I would agree with your choice, it is not nearly so clear-cut as you imply. A [google ngram on "years of reasearch have/has"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=years+of+research+have%2Cyears+of+research+has&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyears%20of%20research%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyears%20of%20research%20has%3B%2Cc0) shows "has" is less common than "have", but still running at half the incidence. Quantified expressions are tricky: " number of people have" is far more common than "a number of people has".

Comment: *"This bag of apples has worms in them,"* or *"this bag of apples have worms in them"*? Or do you have to rephrase it entirely because all the pluralities don't agree, and you can't say *"this bag of apples has worms in it"*?

Comment: I would say and would have no problem understanding "This bag of apples has worms". Without specifying whether the apples or the bag contain or contains the worms (implicitly it is the bag in my version), I don't see a problem, as a bag with worms and apples is not more or less attractive depending on the worms being in the apples as well as in the bag.

Comment: @colinfine The danger of Ngrams is that it reports incorrect usages, too.

Comment: @DavidM: The danger of "correct" is that it becomes divorced from what the language actually is.

Comment: @ColinFine Fair enough (in fact, I've up voted your comment).  But, I think my point stands.  Ngrams will report any usage that occurs with frequency.  This means it will report people using *to* instead of *too*, for example.  That is **clearly incorrect** and my biggest pet peeve!

Comment: @DavidM: yes, it will report mistakes, it is true. But my understanding is that it scans books rather than more ephemeral media, so typos are likely to be comparatively rare.

Comment: @ColinFine Would that we lived in a world where books had no typos!  This would spare us the entire works of Cormac McCarthy which border on illiterate!

Comment: @DavidM: of course books have typos. But systematic spelling errors like _to_ for _too_ are unlikely, so any **particular** error is likely to be rare in the corpus.

Comment: @ColinFine I agree with you.  I'm just pointing out that less preferable usages creep into language frequently, and will be picked up by Ngrams.  The process of editing makes it rarer, but not unheard of.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the actual usage stats from the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), singular agreement in this construction is possible, but rather uncommon:

```
decades of research has      2
decades of research have    14
decades of [nn*] has         4
decades of [nn*] have       60
centuries of [nn*] has       2
centuries of [nn*] have     14
months of [nn*] has          7
months of [nn*] have        21
```

Looking at the [British National Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/), again both variants are not unheard of, but the corpus size is too small to say anything decisively:

```
decades of [nn*] has         1
decades of [nn*] have        0
centuries of [nn*] has       0
centuries of [nn*] have      3
months of [nn*] has          2
months of [nn*] have         3
```

In conclusion, when writing for an international audience, I would favor plural. When writing for a local audience, I would favor whatever comes more naturally to me in my local dialect.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @oerkelens, research is almost irrelevant here because the the subject is 'Decades of *x*'

> Decades of people
>
> Decades of opinions
>
> Decades of knowledge

It doesn't matter what there are decades of, **have** is still the appropriate word.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether you're talking about the research or the decades. If you mean "Research which took decades", use the singular verb (research is a mass noun so it doesn't take plural verbs); if you mean "Decades, which were spent doing research", use the plural.

For example, "The decades of research were the happiest time of my life" but "Decades of research was needed to solve the problem." (Similarly, "tons of concrete was needed to fill the hole.")

Answer (score 0):

What I do in these cases is ask: has the *research* shown, or have the *decades* shown. You could make a case for both, but the case for *research* is stronger. So I'd recommend:

> Decades of research has shown ...

Comment: If you want the research to show something, the sentence should be "after decades, research has show". Unless you would want to see this as a [hypallage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypallage)?

Comment: There is an admitted logical consistency to this.  But, it sounds very foreign to my ear.

Comment: Also, you could easily omit of research and maintain the meaning of the sentence. If you omit decades, the meaning shifts dramatically.